# How to add a preload.js script to expo-electron app?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, expo, electron-builder

I have been working on an expo electron app that uses @expo/electron-adapter so that the same codebase can be used for android, ios, and desktop (mac, windows, linux). But most of the files are autogenerated and I can't able to add a preload.js script to it like for a normal electron app. I have placed the preload.js file in `electron/main` folder. And while creating BrowserWindow passed this `webPreferences: { preload: path.join('preload.js') }` option to it. But the preload.js is not loading at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by registering `preload.js` script in the `electron-webpack.js`. To load `preload.js` script to the electron app. This has to be the directory structure and contents of `electron-webpack.js`.

##### The directory structure:

```
electron 
└───main
│   └───index.js
│   └───preload.js
│   
electron-webpack.js
```

##### electron-webpack.js

```
const { withExpoAdapter } = require('@expo/electron-adapter');

module.exports = withExpoAdapter({
  projectRoot: __dirname,
  main: {
    extraEntries: ['@/preload.js'],
  },
});
```

Comment: What goes in main here? Index.js for example. Also the ```@expo/electron-adapter``` seems to be very outdated.